# Best way to implement Twilio conference timeout? (Second participant never picks up)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twilio

We are using Twilio's conference call for creating calls between 2 or more parties.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls

When a caller(A) calls Twilio number a conference is created on the server using C# Rest API and we then add the caller(A) to a conference. Using the conference statuscallback when caller(A) joins conference we then call other parties using the Conference.ParticipantResource.Create() method and a foreach loop to call a group of people whos role is labeled ADMIN (Could be from 1 to 9 parties) with a timeout of 30 seconds and a statuscallback.

How do I determine if no one answers the call via statuscallback after say 35 seconds?

I would like to send caller(A) to a voicemail if no one picks up. But the problem Im have is  that the callback fires after each called ADMIN dont answer or rejects the call. I know this is by design but Im curious to know how to know when all callers (Admins) didnt pick up the call and send original caller to voicemail. And if one admin picks up to stop calling other admins.

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Twilio Evangelist here,

Sorry that you're having trouble building the conference line in a way that suits your needs. Twilio does not have a feature that will maintain the state of different callers being added to a conference line.

I would suggest the following.

1. Create a collection that represents the list of your admins (and the application should have a way to update a single admin's state for when they've been contacted).
2. As you go about contacting the admins, you'll want to update state as the app attempts to reach them. This way you can respond to a person picking up the phone or alternatively redirecting to voicemail accordingly within your code. This will also make it easy to know when your code has attempted to call everyone.
3. If no one picks up, then you'll be able to redirect your original caller accordingly by modifying their call in-progress (which you can do with [this tutorial here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress)).

Let me know if you run into any issues.